# Preventing spam direct POST request customer registrations in Magento

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento

I've begun to have some issues with spam POST requests on a Magento site where a bot is making spam users (this is even with the action attribute being removed, captcha, etc) as these bots I believe are just making direct POST requests to the standard Magento account url.

Here's 3 examples of valid POST requests I've seen in the log:

```
x.x.x.x - - [06/Nov/2017:13:54:47 -0500] "POST /customer/account/createpost/ HTTP/1.1" 302 - "https://www.example.com/customer/account/create/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.75 Safari/537.36"

x.x.x.x - - [05/Nov/2017:11:34:42 -0500] "POST /customer/account/createpost/ HTTP/1.1" 302 - "https://www.example.com/customer/account/create/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36"

x.x.x.x - - [05/Nov/2017:19:33:15 -0500] "POST /customer/account/createpost/ HTTP/1.1" 302 - "https://www.example.com/customer/account/create/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36"
```

I've anonymized the IP addresses at the beginning, as well as the url. However, notice that the 2nd url is `/customer/account/create/` while the first url is `/customer/account/createpost/`

Here's 3 examples of spam POST requests:

```
112.96.164.18 - - [05/Nov/2017:11:43:43 -0500] "POST /customer/account/createpost/ HTTP/1.1" 302 - "https://www.example.com/customer/account/createpost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0"

112.96.164.18 - - [05/Nov/2017:12:03:17 -0500] "POST /customer/account/createpost/ HTTP/1.1" 302 - "https://www.example.com/customer/account/createpost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0"

112.96.100.2 - - [05/Nov/2017:13:53:45 -0500] "POST /customer/account/createpost/ HTTP/1.1" 302 - "https://www.example.com/customer/account/createpost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0"
```

As far as I can tell on every single spam request, both the first and second url are `/customer/account/createpost/`

What is the 2nd url in this, compared to the first? Is one where the request was sent and the other where it came from?

`/customer/account/createpost/` should probably never be the origin, since that's where the form is actually sent, and visiting it directly redirect `/customer/account/create/`

**My main question is, how do I reliably block the second set of POST requests?**

Comment: @McNab, just posted a solution. Please let me know your feedback on the same

Comment: [this post](https://www.sonassi.com/blog/combating-spam-user-registration-magento) may be helpful.

Comment: @Piyush - I read that article, Ben knows his stuff and it's a recent article but it's not actually that helpful for this problem.  It's direct post so Captchas are no use, and the IPs, user agents and countries change all the time.  The only useful part is the clean up script.

Comment: @McNab can you tell me your magento version?

Comment: @Piyush - this is happening on patched CE 1.7.0.2 install.

Comment: @McNab the action `createpost` is fired when customer registration form is submitted, in Magento version 1.9 and later, magento is using form key validation for security inhancement, and it will not allow to create customer untill its validate the form key like it is happening in your case, i will suggest you to update your magento version and also update your custom theme file for the form key

Comment: @Piyush - Like, I said, the system is fully patched. SUPEE-6788, SUPEE-7405 and SUPEE-8788 have all added security enhancements to the Mage_Customers AccountController and there is no custom registration theme file.

Comment: @Piyush the many installs I'm having this issue with are also fully patched. The bots seem to make 2 requests back to back, in the first one I'm guessing it's recording what the formkey inputs value is to use in the 2nd request. I can easily mass create spam customers with Postman with no problem.

Comment: Can I make a suggestion, you could change the subject of the question to `Preventing spam direct POST request customer registrations in Magento` or something like that.  It'll flag to other users straight away what the intention of the Q&A is more than the current question title.

Comment: @McNab and done!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally found a way to prevent all forms of spam customer accounts from being created in the latest version of Magento.

We initially had put Googles recaptcha on all of our forms including the customer create form so we were surprised when we were suddenly being hit with tons of spam accounts.

The first approach we tried was verifying that the referrer header showed the correct URL, which stopped the bots for a few days until they started spoofing the referrer.

Turns out these bots were just sending requests to /customer/account/createpost/ directly without ever accessing the site directly. There were always 2 requests for each spam customer, a GET request (I'm assuming it was recording what the formkey field was) and then a POST request. As no javascript was running it was just bypassing our check for if the recaptcha was correctly verified and sending the request anyways.

What actually ended up solving it isn't nearly as clean as the invisible recaptcha, but has prevented bots for over a week now...

**Enable Magentos default captcha.**

System -> Configuration -> Customer Configuration -> CAPTCHA

**Set it to Yes for Enabled, and select just the Create User form, then you have to set the Displaying Mode to Always.** This last part is *very important* because this is the only thing that will stop ALL direct POST requests to /customer/account/createpost/ that don't include the correct captcha response. If you don't set displaying mode to always, then the bots will still be able to just mass make customers. As nobody that is not a bot should be submitting direct requests without using the form anyways, this won't prevent any legitimate registrations.

We left it off all the forms besides "Create user" since that's the only form option that really gets spam. No reason to put a captcha on creating a user while checking out since they're spending money.

It's sad that we couldn't use Google's Invisible reCaptcha, but the built in Magento one is the only one integrated enough to prevent all direct POST requests.

Comment: Very useful info, I think your comment about the first request relating to the form key makes sense too.  Can I ask, are any of your affected sites v 1.9.3.x ?

Comment: @McNab yep they were all 1.9.3.x, and this appears to have blocked all the spam we were receiving on about 10+ clients sites.

Comment: Thanks Octoxan, that's really good to know.  Good effort, looks like this one is the answer then after all :)

Comment: thanks! I activated CAPTCH but did not do the display mode to always and had been getting sick amount of spam mostly in russian.  will try this and report back.

Answer (score 5):

So I created a simple php file with a echo statement. Then added a `.htaccess` with below content

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/customer/account/createpost/$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://dev\.tarunlalwani\.com:8088/customer/account/create/$
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
```

Now some tests

**Wrong Referer**

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Referer: http://dev.tarunlalwani.com:8088/customer/account/creates/" dev.tarunlalwani.com:8088/customer/account/createpost/
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /customer/account/createpost/
on this server.<br />
</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at dev.tarunlalwani.com Port 8088</address>
</body></html>
```

**Correct Referer**

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Referer: http://dev.tarunlalwani.com:8088/customer/account/create/" dev.tarunlalwani.com:8088/customer/account/createpost/
Tarun here
```

As you can anytime the referer is not exactly `http://dev.tarunlalwani.com:8088/customer/account/create/` the POST request is denied. I think same should work for you. Just remember to update the domain name and remove the port. Change `http` to `https` if needed

Answer (score 1):

Your first question, yes the two URLs in the logs are the URL being requested, and, if the browser provided it, the referring URL for that request. Conventionally they're in that order; the other information are things like HTTP return code, the User-Agent string, etc..

If your current spam requests are so predictable, then you might want to just block them on the basis of their user agent and/or originating IP range, as both of those look consistent in your examples. For example using user-agent:

```
# in .htaccess
RewriteCond %{USER_AGENT} ^Mozilla/5.0.+WOW64.+Gecko/20100101$ 
RewriteRule  ^.*  -  [G,L]
```

Obviously that won't be foolproof but can be useful.

Or, selectively blocking that spammer from that specific script, unless they come from the right place, by relying on that referrer field (which the *client* provides) is the other route & the other solution. My preference is to throw out clowns altogether if possible, unless there are valid reasons for letting them into your site at all.

Answer (score 1):

I found this guide https://perishablepress.com/protect-post-requests/ to be very useful. 
While not focused especially on Magento, it shows multiple reasonable  methods of defense .
Unfortunately, mod_rewrite is limited to relatively simple rules.

If the problems persist you might consider using mod_security (or other application firewall), there is arather good general ruleset available in owasp-crs https://github.com/SpiderLabs/owasp-modsecurity-crs . 
Of course, this has to be deployed on server side and needs some tweaking for it to work well, but it's a very good step up in protection and worth it.